# Wildcards in an email address with qmail?

Tags: qmail

I'm trying to set up an email address in qmail such that a unique identifier can be passed as part of the email address.

For example:

reply-123@example.com, reply-345@example.com, reply-99999@example.com would all go to the 'reply' user and be sent to the same shell script.  Currently, email sent to reply@example.com goes to the script and I pass the unique id in the subject or message body.  Would be grateful for any suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a default qmail setup, you can do exactly what you suggest... anything following a dash is ignored for delivery purposes, so reply-anything@example.com will be processed by the .qmail-reply file, where you would presumably send the mail to your script and look at the address to obtain the identifier.

We use this for bounce tracking - if the email is to xyz@example.com, and the sender is bounce@sender.com, then the from address is written this way:

bounce-xyz=example.com@sender.com

And a script flags the address as no good.

EDIT:
I screwed this up a bit - I guess I'm rusty on qmail.  The alias thing doesn't work by default as I stated above.  To support extensions for bounce@sender.com, you need a .qmail-default file in ~bounce.

See the "extension addresses" (section 4.1.5) on LWQ: http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html

Comment: I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing.  The problem is that email sent to reply-xyz@example.com fails with a 550 mailbox not found error.  Email sent to reply@example.com works fine.  I have tried to set up the reply address both as a user (/var/qmail/mailnames/mydomain.com/reply/.qmail) and as an alias (/var/qmail/alias/.qmail-reply)  Is there some trick to getting qmail to ignore the address portion between the dash and the @?

Comment: Please see my edit - I was missing a step for the catch-alls to work.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  I've reread LWQ section 4.1.5 so many times over the past few days that I'm starting to see it in my sleep!  I can't even get a simple (non wildcard -default) extension to work and I'm beginning to suspect that this is a Plesk related problem.  I've gone to the parallels support forum for help to see if they have any advice.